# How to put image properly on pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, badge

I have blank id card's with following size:

[image]
[image]

For Europe printing is `85mmx55mm`. So i made a background image using Google power point as `mm` to `pixel`: 
[image]

But when i put it in the `TCPDF` then the image is not fitted exactly on the `85mmx55mm`:

[image]
[image]

My code for TCPDF was as following:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', array(55,85));
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 1);
// image in pixel: 319 × 207  
$pdf->Image('background_image.jpg', 0, 0);
```

What am i doing wrong? Why the background_image.jpg is larger then array(55,85)?